# Can silica gel beads cause silicosis if crushed?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, toxicity

Can silica gel beads (which I believe are amorphous) when crushed to dust cause silicosis?

Comment: search the web. Always search the web. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis#Silica . However, despite stated inability of amourphous silica to cause silicosis, any form of mineral dust is not healthy for lungs.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't. Silica beads dust may cause irritation to the skin and eyes. Unlike silica crystalline,  synthetic amorphous silica gel is  indurated, and so does not cause silicosis.